# Is there a way to make the phone stop ringing in M.U.D. TV?

Tags: mud-tv

In M.U.D. TV, there is a phone in your office which rings incessantly.  There does not appear to be any way to answer it.

Is there a way to make it stop ringing, or does it just ring continuously, to make you not want to be in your office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now got a strong feeling now that the answer is 'no'